# AssetManager libgdx Asset not loaded

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am having an issue with my AssetManager in libgdx, I am creating it in my Main class and have a getMethod to return the assetManager to my screens. When I go to assetManager.get(etc.) in my screens classes It says

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 563
                  Process: com.johnny.gamerpg, PID: 9855
                  com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: 
                    Asset not loaded: data/backgrounds/mainMenu.png
```

This is my create() in the Main Class.

```
public void create()
{

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    assetManager = new AssetManager();
    assetManager.load("data/backgrounds/mainMenu.png", Texture.class);

    startTime = TimeUtils.millis();
    this.setScreen(new Splash(this));


    if(assetManager.update() && TimeUtils.timeSinceMillis(startTime) > 3000)
    {
        setMainMenuScreen();
    }
}
```

This is my MainMenu class constructor.

```
public MainMenu(GameControl gam)
{
    this.game = gam;
    assetManager = gam.getAssestManager();

    background = assetManager.get("data/backgrounds/mainMenu.png", Texture.class);

}
```

setMainMenuScreen()

```
public void setMainMenuScreen()
{
    setScreen(new MainMenu(this));
}
```

Comment: Change `assetManager.update()` to `assetManager.finishLoading()`

Comment: @Marius does assetManager.finishLoading() return a true or false to make it switch screen from Splash to MainMenu if all assets are loaded?

Comment: finishLoading blocks until all assets are loaded, so it uses update() internally

Answer (score 2):

Do you ever get to the menu screen? you switch to Splash() before assetmanager is done loading and before the 3000 milisecs. Even before you check for any of those.

assetManager.update() will return false until the asset is loaded. assetManager.update() is meant to be called every frame until it returns true. This means that you should check for

```
if(assetManager.update()){
    //done loading
}
```

in your render()

You should start with moving

```
if(assetManager.update() && TimeUtils.timeSinceMillis(startTime) > 3000)
{
    setMainMenuScreen();
}
```

into render() and rethink how and when you switch to the Splash screen.

Comment: Well My goal was to have the splash screen show until all the assets had loaded then switch to my main screen. How would I go about that?